# How to get same cursor(hand) on links in all browser?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

In firefox on link hand cursor is showing which is ok but in IE7 it's showing text cursor.

How to get same cursor(hand) on links in all browser?

Can i add something in CSS reset to get cursor in all  browser on links.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `cursor: pointer` not `cursor: hand`...

Comment: would it be good idea to keep this in css reset. `a, a:link {cursor:pointer)`?

Comment: Anchors should be set to cursor pointer by default in every browser, you shouldn't need to reset it. You need to make sure your other classes *don't* use cursor hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use cursor: pointer instead of cursor: hand